# Authorize google api requests to list users

Tags: python, google-api

I want to get list of users google api but face an issue
My steps are:

1. Created Service account with domain wide delegation and listed scopes (same as in the script)
2. Downloaded json file with private key

On execution of the next script

```
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import requests

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('key.json', scopes=[
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'
])
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
refresh = credentials.refresh(auth_req)
response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=domain.com',
                    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials.token}'})
```

Response is:

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
      "errors": [
         {
            "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "forbidden"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the next solution

1. console.cloud.google.com => APIs & Services > Credentials
2. Create Credentials > OAuth Client ID > Desktop APp
3. Saved key as 'credentials.json'

The rest id described here

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']

#

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Admin SDK Directory API.
    Prints the emails and names of the first 10 users in the domain.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            print('Refreshing token')
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'python_admin.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Admin SDK Directory API
    print('Getting the first 10 users in the domain')
    service_users = service.users()
    results = service_users.list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=10, orderBy='email').execute()
    users = results.get('users', [])

    service_users.insert()

    if not users:
        print('No users in the domain.')
    else:
        print('Users:')
        for user in users:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(user['primaryEmail'],
                user['name']['fullName']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For the first time I had to authorize request in the browser, after that access and refresh token could be used for next requests. Except manual authorization for the first time - works fine